# How to use dynamic id for HTML element in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

I am trying to create drop-down box dynamically, here I can create dynamically drop-down boxes but after that, I need to load the values from DB, so I need to do on-click function. Here I try the using dynamic id but it is not working how to solve this.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    
    $("#ssr").click(function(){
        
      alert("Test");    
    
      load_shift_code();
    });
  
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    for(var i=0;i<4;i++){
    var a=["html","css","java","javascript","php","c++","node.js","ASP","JSP","SQL"];
    var employee_name =emp_name();  
    var table_body = document.getElementById("table_head");
    var row = table_body.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2)
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    var cell6 = row.insertCell(5)
    var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
    var cell8 = row.insertCell(7);
    var cell9 = row.insertCell(8);
    var cell10 = row.insertCell(9);
    var cell11 = row.insertCell(10);
    var cell12 = row.insertCell(11);
    
    var drop_down_list =document.getElementById("select");
  var idx="ssr";
    cell1.innerHTML = employee_name[i];
    cell2.innerHTML = employee_name[i];
    cell3.innerHTML = "<select  id='" + idx +"'><option value='default'>default</option></select>";
    cell4.innerHTML = "<select  id='select'><option value='default'>default</option></select>";
    cell5.innerHTML = "<select  id='select'><option value='default'>default</option></select>";
    cell6.innerHTML = "<select  id='select'><option value='default'>default</option></select>";
    cell7.innerHTML = "<select  id='select'><option value='default'>default</option></select>";
    cell8.innerHTML = "<select  id='select'><option value='default'>default</option></select>";
    cell9.innerHTML = "<select  id='select'><option value='default'>default</option></select>";
    cell10.innerHTML ="<select  id='select'><option value='default'>default</option></select>";
    cell11.innerHTML ="<select  id='select'><option value='default'>default</option></select>";
    
}
  
  
  
});
```

Comment: in code snippet add HTML code also.

Comment: @ShivKumarBaghel html part is no need ,because  i put the html part as string in this code ,

Answer (score 0):

Put the code to add the event listener to the element with id `ssr` *after the code that creates the element and puts it in the DOM*. As posted  `$("#ssr")` won't find anything.